# Negative complex exponentiation

Tags: c, complex-numbers

I want to calculate complex number angles and magnitude and I good with them

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

double pi = 4 * atan(1.0);

int main() {
    double complex z = cexp(I * -1 * pi * 1.2 - 1);
    printf("%f + %f * i\n", creal(z), cimag(z));

    double complex base = clog(z);
    printf("%f + %f * i\n", creal(base), cimag(base));
 
    double arg = carg(base);
    printf(" Angle of z in radian %f and as degree %f \n", arg, arg * 180 / pi);

    double magnitude = cabs(base);
    printf("Magnitude of z %f \n", magnitude);

    return 0;
}
```

this program prints

```
-0.297621 + 0.216234 * i
-1.000000 + 2.513274 * i
 Angle of z in radian 1.949480 and as degree 111.696984 
Magnitude of z 2.704912
```

But, This result don't have negative imaginary component.
But all complex numbers have positive one.
How can I get a value at the third quadrant of the complex plane?

Comment: What output do you expect? [Edit] your question.

Comment: `double pi = 4 * atan(1.0);` not valid C code in global space.  maxemilian, what C compiler are you using?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I expect a value at third quadrant or fourth quadrant area any value. I need negative imaginary component for weather works or not

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Code OSS (VS code) based GCC under Linux

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yeah normally gives error but try `"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}", `after              `"-lm"` this line at `tasks.json` file. Likewise, `gcc -lm filename.c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on `cexp(I * -1*pi*1.2-1)`.
The angle is `-1.2*pi` what is equivalent to `-1.2pi + 2*pi = 0.8pi`. This angle is pointing into the second quadrant where real part is negative and imaginary part is *positive*.

```
0.8 * pi ~= 2.51327412287
```

As in value of `clog(z)` from your example.
Everything works fine. Some intuitive explanation why positive angles become negative is following example:

*Turning 200 degrees right will place you in the same orientation as turning -160 degrees right.*

To get a number in the 3rd quadrant the angle must between (pi ... 1.5 pi) plus 2*k*pi where k is arbitrary integer number. Try 1.2 * pi.

```
-0.297621 + -0.216234 * i
-1.000000 + -2.513274 * i
 Angle of z in radian -1.949480 and as degree -111.696984 
Magnitude of z 2.704912
```